# Rails Asset Not Generating Correct URL for Precompiled Asset

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am developing a site with Ruby on Rails 4 and am having issues with paths to some CSS files.

I have the following assets which are not included in my `applicaiton.sass` file:

- mobile.scss
- mozilla.scss
- msie.scss
- opera.scss
- webkit.scss

I have included them in my `application.rb` to be precompiled using the following:

```
config.assets.precompile += [
  'mobile.css',
  'mozilla.css',
  'msie.css',
  'opera.css',
  'webkit.css'
]
```

On my production server I have run the following commands (Note: the `touch` command is to make sure the app restarts and clears the cache since I am using Phusion Passenger with Nginx as my server):

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

After running the above commands I noticed the assets were precompiled and reside in my `public/assets/` directory. They are also correctly listed in the `manifest.json` file in the `public/assets/` directory.

When I load the site in my browser and look at the source code I notice the browser specific CSS file is not using the correct asset path. It shows:

```
<link href="/assets/application-ec1031f251a585c79d4404ef2899f6d1.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/stylesheets/webkit.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

While I expect to see:

```
<link href="/assets/application-ec1031f251a585c79d4404ef2899f6d1.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/webkit-70899fec75bb8eae24edae491a94f73a.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My view looks uses the following code:

```
<% if @mobile %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :mobile %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :msie if @browser == 'Internet Explorer' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :opera if @browser == 'Opera' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :mozilla if @browser == 'Mozilla' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :webkit if @browser == 'Webkit' %>
<% end %>
```

My question is shouldn't the `webkit.css` path be outputting correctly or is there something I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When Rails prints the path like `/stylesheets/webkit.css`, it means it wasn't able to find a precompiled version of that asset.

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't find it when it created it successfully and it resides in the `public/assets/` folder?

Comment: Unfortunately not and I haven't had time to do too much digging.

Comment: I had the same problem, but as specified in the Rails guides you need to include any other manifest file in the precompile array. config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you precompile assets in production mode (assuming you followed [the Rails asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), all of your assets under `app/assets` will be compiled into `application.css`.  Thus, all files listed here are already in `application.css`:

```
config.assets.precompile += [
  'mobile.css',
  'mozilla.css',
  'msie.css',
  'opera.css',
  'webkit.css'
]
```

This is the recommended way to do it as one larger file is faster to load than several smaller files, as the HTTP request and response is generally the slowest part of the process for the app.

If you absolutely need to conditionally include stylesheets based on the browser type per your code, you would either:

1. Remove them from the asset pipeline manifest in the `application.css` and leave the CSS files in the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory, then include them as you do above.
2. Move the CSS files outside of the asset pipeline directories and then include them as you have in your view code above.  This way, they won't be compiled into the `application.css` file and can be loaded separately

Just keep in mind that either of these options defeat one of the main intents of the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm being a little too obvious, but have you stated in your production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```